# Android/Java: How to create personalized schemes without https in it?

Tags: java, android

How to use schemes with parameters without using ***https*** ? It works only with https, I would like to use other piece of code for example opening the app with the url :

```
myapp://open
```

Here is my actual code:

```
  <intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="open" />

    </intent-filter>
```

I tried `<data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="open" />` but doesn't work.
I tried in Google Lens (and other scan app) that doesn't make me opening schemes that doesn't contain "https"

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="33"/> <!-- NEW CODE -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Thank you

Comment: yep, it doesn't work

Comment: If a QR code reader only works with https URL this might be a security restriction. For my answer `myapp://open` also works from a QR code reader (e.g. the `com.gamma.scan`). Tested on Android 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to require at least a custom scheme and host like the following example:

```
<activity ... exported=true>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="open" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can test it using

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d myapp://open
```

By executing this command the activity that is associated with the intent-filter will open.

If it still doesn't work then may be the used QR code reader is not usuable with custom schemes. For example the open source app [Binary Eye](https://github.com/markusfisch/BinaryEye) ([`de.markusfisch.android.binaryeye`](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/de.markusfisch.android.binaryeye/)) has no problem opening an app using a QR code with a link `myapp://open`.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to investigate, I will report you my tests

Comment: I tried multiple times, impossible to make it work. Don't you think it is a Right permission problem ?

Comment: @ΩlostA I used my standard sample and experimental app, which only has INTERNET permission and added the intent-filter to the main activity (app has minSdkVersion 15). I tested on Google Pixel 4 latest Android 12 + all sec updates. Can you start the app using the adb command or the Binary Eye QR code app?

Comment: Oh yes, you are perfectly right. The Binary Eye QR code app works with that. What is the problem with Google Lens and the other app you think ?

Comment: @ΩlostA I would assume that the Google apps are restricted to http(s) links for security reasons. Custom schemes are primarily for app-to-app invocation. In general placing custom scheme URLs in QR codes is a bad idea as they can only work if a certain app is installed and otherwise fail without a proper description how to solve the situation.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do it like this so by proposing the two schemes with https :) and I will propose your app to others

Comment: @ΩlostA I think that is a misunderstanding, my personal app I used for testing is not published. I am not involved in any of the mentioned QR code readers. Binary Eye was just the first QR app I found on f-droid.

Comment: Oh ok, in all case, thank you for your light on that subject :)